# How to test a single custom 404 error page in rails test environment in ci?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, capybara, custom-error-pages

We have a custom 404 error page.

We wanted to test it so we tried changing

```
config/environments/test.rb
```

to have `config.consider_all_requests_local = true`

which worked - but did it for all tests.  We want to do it for just the one test.
We tried using

```
before do
  Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local = false
end

after do
  Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local = true
end
```

and that worked in our test environment locally but not in our CircleCI test environment which was still seeing the 'rails debug' page.

How could we make that single test work for the custom error page in CircleCI ?

Comment: Out of curiosity - what are you testing? Just that it is shown when there is a 404 error, or is there additional functionality you're trying to run with the 404 page?

Comment: Why can't you just visit 404 page? Capybara.. `visit page_path('page_not_found')
  expect(page.status_code).to eq(404)`

Comment: Needs to be our custom error page with a link to root_path, not the rails dev/test error page with debug info.